# Firebase function deploying, but not showing up in console

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

This question is essentially the same as question [44799104](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44799104/can-not-display-deployed-cloud-function-in-firebase-console?rq=1), only that I provide my index.js (and the only answer there was not helpful, as I do include 'exports').

In short, I have deployed my function successfully,

[image: Console output]

but it does not show in the console. Where am I going wrong?
Here is my index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var delayInMilliseconds = 5000;


exports.copyRoom= functions.database.ref('/RoomsOwn/${AuthUid}').onWrite((event) => {

    var uid = event.params.AuthUid;
    console.log('AuthID: ' + uid);
    var object = event.data.val();
    console.log('Whole Object: ', object);

    setTimeout(function() {
    return admin.database.ref('/RoomsOthers/${uid}').set(object);
    }, delayInMilliseconds);

  });
```

Comment: Well in my case I had a function in the form of `const onCreateUser = ....` and then exporting the function like `module.exports = onCreateUser;`. But when I tried `exports.onCreateUser` it worked!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You didn't actually deploy that function when you ran `firebase deploy`.  If you had successfully deployed it, the name of the function would have appeared in the Firebase CLI output.

Make sure you:

1. Actually saved the file with the function you're trying to deploy.
2. The file is in the correct directory. For JavaScript projects, the default is `functions/index.js`
3. Are deploying the correct project from the correct directory.

Comment: Thanks Doug, item 2 was the helpful one. My index.js was laying outside the functions folder.

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43020173/can-not-see-the-firebase-function-deployed

Comment: In my case I'm using typescript and `firebase deploy` was not building the lib folder again. I guess it was caused by a interface I was importing ouside of the functions folder scope. I delete the `lib` folder and remove this interface and I looks like it's back to normal

Answer (score 4):

In my case I just had to cd into the functions folder before deploy. Note that you should be getting this in your output:

[image: Cloud functions output including function url and a step about packaging and uploading functions folder]

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was in the name of the function. My function name was `fooBar` but I was using `foobar`.

```
firebase deploy --only functions:foobar // Incorrect
firebase deploy --only functions:fooBar // Correct
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using Typescript and was importing an interface that was outside the `function`'s folder scope. Once I removed that import, it was deployed as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to RETURN the firebase function from inside of a wrapper function.

```
export const myWrapper = (database: any, url: any) => {
//don't forget the return keyword here!!
  return functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => { }

}
```

Hope it helps someone down the line.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I was importing some types/interfaces from a level above the functions directory.  Therefore, when building, the `index.js` was in a different location than it was previously.

I had to go to the `functiond` directory's `package.json` and update the `main` to the correct location of `index.js` within the `functions` directory.

Then deployed fine.