# Firebase Functions code deployed but not visible in console

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I'm having issues with the Firebase Functions. As soon as I execute `firebase deploy` in the terminal, I get the following message

```
=== Deploying to 'xxxxxxxx'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint D:\Flutter Projects\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx\functions
> eslint .

+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

+  Deploy complete!

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/xxxxxxxx/overview
```

But when I take a look in the Firebase Functions console, it says "waiting for your first implementation".

This is my `index.js` file inside the functions folder:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("../functions/xxxxxxxx-firebase-adminsdk.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com"
});

var payload = {
    notification: {
      title: "Test title",
      body: "Test notification",
      image: ""
    },
  };

var options = {
    priority: "high",
    to: '/topics/all'
}

function sendPushNotification(payload){
    admin.messaging().sendToTopic("all", payload)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("Successfully sent message: ", response);
        return null;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error sending message: ", error);
    });
}

setInterval(() => {
  sendPushNotification(payload);
}, 3600000);

module.exports.sendPushNotification = sendPushNotification;
```

When running `node index.js` the code works as expected. I'm not sure if I exported the function the right way, so maybe Firebase Functions doesn't know which function to deploy. The goal is that Firebase Functions sends a notification every hour (just for testing purposes) to all devices. How can I achieve this?

Note: I've checked the following (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49017318/firebase-function-deploying-but-not-showing-up-in-console) thread):

1. Actually saved the file with the function i'm trying to deploy.
2. The file is in the correct directory. For JavaScript projects, the default is functions/index.js
3. I am deploying the correct project from the correct directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to refactor your code to use a [scheduled function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions).

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const serviceAccount = require("../functions/xxxxxxxx-firebase-adminsdk.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
});

const payload = {
  notification: {
    title: "Test title",
    body: "Test notification",
    image: "",
  },
};

const options = {
    priority: "high",
    to: '/topics/all'
}

exports.sendPushNotification = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 hour')
  .onRun((context) => {
    admin.messaging().sendToTopic("all", payload)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Successfully sent message: ", response);
        return null;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error sending message: ", error);
        return null;
      });
  });
```